# Hide ActionBar MenuItems when Navigation Drawer slides for any amount

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a Navigation Drawer that hides the menu items in the ActionBar whenever the drawer is opened.

I am following google's documentation, however their code does not produce the expected behavior.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Using this code, the menu items are hidden when the drawer becomes *completely opened* , and shown when the drawer becomes completely closed.

However, the Gmail app behaves differently.  The menu items are hidden as soon as the drawer *opens by any amount*.  This is the behavior I want.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Have you tried this:

1. Use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` whenever you toggle the nav drawer, by measuring the sliding offset.
2. Iterate over each menu item in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and hide it.

   ```
   @Override

   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

       // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
       boolean drawerOpen = shouldGoInvisible;
       hideMenuItems(menu, !drawerOpen);
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   private void hideMenuItems(Menu menu, boolean visible)
   {

       for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){

           menu.getItem(i).setVisible(visible);

       }
   }
   ```

Detecting how much the nav drawer has slided:

```
     mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener(){
                    float mPreviousOffset = 0f;

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
                         super.onDrawerClosed(arg0);
                         shouldGoInvisible = false;
                         invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
                         super.onDrawerOpened(arg0);
                         shouldGoInvisible = true;
                         invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float slideOffset) {
             super.onDrawerSlide(arg0, slideOffset);
             if(slideOffset > mPreviousOffset && !shouldGoInvisible){
                shouldGoInvisible = true;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }else if(mPreviousOffset > slideOffset && slideOffset < 0.5f && shouldGoInvisible){
                shouldGoInvisible = false;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            mPreviousOffset = slideOffset;


        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // or use states of the drawer to hide/show the items

        }});
```

Note: `shouldGoInvisible` is class field.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm doing.  The problem is, that code isn't being called until the drawer is *completely* open, as opposed to as soon as its opened, even a little bit, as it does in Gmail.

I'm calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() in the onDrawerOpen() and onDrawerClose() of my ActionBarDrawerToggle object.

Comment: @Synergy807 I have tested and this works flawless like you have desired. It hides the drawer whenever it is slided by any amount, in any direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The onDrawerSlide and onDrawerStateChanged methods where what I needed.

Comment: _shouldGoInvisible is a class field_ Could you show how it's defined?

Comment: `private boolean shouldGoInvisible = false;`

Comment: How to achieve this if the Main Activity has no options Menu but the child fragments have their own?

Comment: I think it will be the same, instead you inflate and hide menu in the fragment since `invalidateOptionsMenu()` will trigger inflation in the fragments too. You just have to take care of the boolean flag (with some setter) to currently displayed fragment.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to override action bar as soon as drawer enters screen and restore action bar the moment drawer is no longer visible (exactly how Gmail behaves as of March 20, 2014) you can use the following code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

  @Override
  public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
    super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);

    boolean isOpened = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    boolean isVisible = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(mDrawerList);

    if (!isOpened && !isVisible) {
      if (newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_IDLE) {
        // drawer just hid completely
        restoreActionBar();
      } else {
        // } else if (newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING) {
        // drawer just entered screen
        overrideActionBar();
      }
    }
  }

  private void restoreActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
  }

  private void overrideActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
  }
};

// Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Modify `restoreActionBar()` and `overrideActionBar()` methods acording to your needs.

There is no need to distinguish between swipes and home button and no need to measure swipe lengths.

### Variation

If you don't want to reference the drawer list view use the following code instead:

```
    boolean isOpened = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
    boolean isVisible = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START);
```

You may want to use `GravityCompat.END` instead depending on what you specified in XML layout.

### Edit - concerning actions

The above example does not hide action bar items relevant to content below the navigation drawer. To do so or show different set of icons when drawer is visible you have to keep track of whether the drawer is opened or closed manually.

In addition to the above code declare `private boolean mDrawerVisible = false` with proper save/restore state handling.
Then modify `mDrawerToggle` inner methods as follows:

```
  private void restoreActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    mDrawerVisible = false;
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
  }

  private void overrideActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    mDrawerVisible = true;
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
  }
```

Finally in `onCreateOptionsMenu` inflate different menu resource or in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` show/hide different actions based on the value of `mDrawerVisible`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd half agree with Nikola but it's sufficient just to update the icons when the drawer state has

Create a global variable to keep track of the drawer state:

```
private int mDrawerState;
```

Set a new DrawerListener:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDrawerStateChanged(int state) {
    mDrawerState = state;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slide) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
});
```

Update the menu visibility:

```
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer);
for(int i=0;i<menu.size();i++){
  // If the drawer is moving / settling or open do not draw the icons
  menu.getItem(i).setVisible(mDrawerState!=DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING &&
      mDrawerState!=DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING && !drawerOpen);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very similar to what I ended up doing!

Comment: Actually, after further investigation, I found that using states does not quite work, at least my implementation.  If you simply put your finger on the edge of the screen, a small slice of the navigation drawer will show (as it does it gmail, etc).  However, it will still display the actionbar menu items.  Does yours do the same thing?

Comment: No, using states seems sufficient on my device.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution for this question:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (navigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        menu.clear();
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!navigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        showLocalContextActionBar();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all menu items, simply use:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    return showActionBarMenu; // boolean value, set it in drawer listeners as class variable
}
```

Then you do not need to visible of each menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer by @Laurence Dawson and simplified it a bit. This solution does not require any class members to be used.

Execute this code during `onCreate()`:

```
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float v) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {}

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int state) {}
    });
```

And override this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    boolean actionsVisibility = !drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(Gravity.START);

    for(int i=0;i<menu.size();i++){
        menu.getItem(i).setVisible(actionsVisibility);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Few notes:

- The above implementation assumes that the view associated with NavigationDrawer has its `layout_gravity` set to `start` in XML.
- Unrelated to OP's question, but annoying: there seems to be some kind of a bug which causes the drawer to stuck along the way. If you do observe this behavior, here is the solution: [Android Navigation Drawer bug using the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044277/android-navigation-drawer-bug-using-the-sample)

Answer (score 0):

I have different code but the same solution:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    hideMenuItems(menu, !mShouldGoInvisible);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
private void hideMenuItems(Menu menu, boolean visible){
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){

        menu.getItem(i).setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

and

```
 @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerListener(boolean opened, int position) {

    if (opened){
        mShouldGoInvisible = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

    } else {
        mShouldGoInvisible = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```