# How to hide OptionsMenu on NavigationDrawer using Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-optionsmenu

I am creating android application and I'm trying to respect as much as possible the latest Android usability standards. In particular, I am preparing the user interface using the navigation drawer, and I'm trying to ensure compatibility with 2.1+ Android versions. To appreciate the problem, the project consists of:

- A main activity;
- A navigation drawer;
- Four fragments (with their associated layouts).

The problem I'm experiencing occurs when opening the navigation drawer: although each `Fragment` has its specific menu, when I open the navigation drawer it is added to the nav drawer menu. I tried in several ways (`invalidateOptionMenu()`, `menu.clear()`, manipulating functions `isDrawerOpen()` and `isDrawerClose()` and more), but I cannot remove the `Fragment`'s menu when opening the navigationdrawer.

These are some snippets of my code, much of it generated by Android Studio, the IDE I'm using:

In main activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

where "global" is a simple menu with a classical "ic_action_overflow".

And in my fragments I've:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1, menu);
}
```

(It's the same of the other `Fragment`s).

Someone can give me some advice on how to act?

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same problem using the boilerplate code generated by Android Studio and got it working by modifying the menu in `NavigationDrawerFragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu()` (in my case, I wanted to clear the menu altogether):

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        menu.clear();
    }
}
```

This is roughly how the options menu is recreated:

1. `NavigationDrawerFragment`, which is generated by the IDE, calls `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` when the drawer is opened or closed.
2. [`onCreateOptionsMenu` gets called](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L2818): The hosting activity and each of the added fragments gets a chance to contribute menu items.
3. [`onPrepareOptionsMenu` gets called](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L2836): Again, the hosting activity and each of the added fragments get a chance to modify the menu.

The fragments are [iterated in the order they were added](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#L1940). There is no way to stop the chain of calls midway in steps 2. and 3.

So the idea is to let `NavigationDrawerFragment` do last-minute changes to the menu in its `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and no other fragments.

If you need to let other fragments do something in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, then you may have to setup those other fragments so they can determine if the drawer is open or not and change their behavior accordingly. This may mean perhaps adding a `isDrawerOpen` method to the hosting activity or passing in the drawer identifiers to the fragment like it's done in `NavigationDrawerFragment.setup()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that `onPrepareOptionsMenu` works better than `onCreateOptionsMenu`. `onCreateOptionsMenu` did nothing with my ActionBar, whereas the same code in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` did gave the desired effect. Perhaps this is because it's a Samsung S4... x|

Comment: @LucasTan There is no clean way, as far as a I know. It worked in my case because no other fragments implemented `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. I've updated my answer to address such cases.

Comment: Isn't this the right answer? That worked for me except for a small delay to hide button which is caused by the animated slide in of drawer fragment.

Answer (score 5):

In your fragment onCreate, add this :

```
setHasOptionsMenu (true);
```

And then hide through onPrepareOptionsMenu. e.g.

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18135409/2558344. Its basically using a boolean to clear items in the navigation drawer and vice versa. But alternatively,  you could declare `Menu menu` as a private variable in your class and use it as: `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, MenuInflater inflater)`.

Then check in your fragments `onStop()`, `onPause()` if it's displaying items or not, if yes then clear them, like:

```
if (menu != null)
    menu.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried using the solution on your link, but I give an error on "public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)" and in return value, because it expects a void value. I've also tried with your solution but I don't understand completely. I've added a private menu variable in my MainActivity.java but the variable is never used. I've update my onStop() and onPause methods too. But what should I do with onCreateOptionMenu() method? Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Do you see the "Menu menu" in onCreateOptionsMenu(...), yeah replace both with "menu" which refers to your local variable. And no need to call onPrepareOptionsMenu(...)

Comment: How does one call onCreateOptionsMenu() again to recreate the menu when I want it shown again ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented the navigation drawer the way Android Studio sets it up for you in its example code with a `NavigationDrawerFragment`, you should have two xml to start with `main.xml` (activity wide actionbar menu items) and `global.xml` (global items). I then added a fragment specific menu which adds items to the "activity menu items" as long as the drawer is closed...

Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this activity
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. 
    // See also showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area 
    // of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

and in your fragments add as you've described above

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Add fragment specific action bar items to activity action bar items.
    // Activity wide items are in main.xml
    // Visible action bar items if navigation drawer is visible/open 
    // are in global.xml
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    }
}
```