# Navigation drawer: When swiping from left edge slowly, the dragging of the menu stops

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

If I swipe from left very fast, this does not happen. But if I swipe from the left edge slowly, often (but not always) the dragging stops and the drawer menu does not respond to further swiping. I have tried it with other Google apps such as Google Books, Maps, or Play Store, but they did not have this problem.

At first, I thought I did something wrong. But I created a new project and selected the main activity type as "Navigation Drawer Activity", and the problem was reproduced. I did not modify the generated project other than changing the SDK/tools/library versions.

How can I solve this problem? I have not attached the source code, as it was reproduced the template project in Android Studio. The followings are my version/configuration.

- Android Studio 3.0.1
- Kotlin
- Compile SDK 27
- Target SDK 27
- Build Tools 27.0.3
- Support versions "27.+"

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044277/android-navigation-drawer-bug-using-the-sample

Comment: Thank you. For some strange reason, after filling the drawer menu with items, this happened less. It still happens once in a while, but I have found that it also sometimes happens in famous Google apps, so I just decided to leave it as it is. But the link you gave to me did address the very same issue. It may be useful, in case if the client wants me to do something about it.