# Why does the Android Navigation Drawer stick? (recreated in official demo app)

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I've implemented the new Navigation Drawer pattern in an Android app and for some reason it will stick with the 20dp tab preview probably close to 10% of the time.

I've implemented it with a complete copy paste of the demo app so I was surprised not to find anyone else having this issue on SO.  Is nobody else seeing this?  It happens on both my test devices and I cannot recreate it at all on any of the google apps that have a drawer.

Any ideas of what might cause this?  I can paste my code but it's the same as the demo app.  The only difference is what I have in my drawer layout (two ListViews and a spinner, but I'm only populating one of the ListViews like the demo app does).

EDIT:  This can be recreated consistently in the official demo app.

A video demonstration: http://youtu.be/aEVHannoYvQ

Comment: I can recreate it pretty consistently by doing a diagonally upward thumb swipe from about 1/3 up the left side of the display edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a open issue on the Android issue Tracker , Star it ;)

[Android Issue Tracker(NavigationDrawer)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=navigation%20drawer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=58183)

hopefully it gets fixed :)

EDIT: Seems there is a fix, read this: [ClickMe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896052/why-does-drawerlayout-sometimes-glitch-upon-opening)

Comment: Thanks for finding that.