# Navigation Drawer appears partially

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

In my app (with AppCompat-v7) it happens sometimes that, after the sliding touch to request the Navigation Drawer, the drawer locks at the beginning of the passage: it appears only partially and DrowerToggle's animated icon remains crooked. What may be due? Thanks

**EDIT 1:** it seems that this behavior of the drawer happens in coincidence with the simultaneous request to execute a *AsyncTask* which will then update the UI from `onPostExecute`. Does anyone have an explanation?

**EDIT 2:** I found this [Why does DrawerLayout sometimes glitch upon opening?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17896052/4274296) very similar question.
I tried the suggested solution with `android:clickable="true"` on the main parent ViewGroup, except the DrawerLayout, of Activity: it works for the majority of cases but not all, and I can not explain how the frequency of the problem is directly related to the intensity of the updates on the UI.

Perhaps both affect: `android:clickable="true"` on the main parent ViewGroup accelerates the response upwards with respect to the management of TouchEvent by Navigation Drawer, while a lower activity of updating the UI promotes proper cancellation of PostDelayed sent to the UI from the same Navigation Drawer in case of crossing the touch slop.

[example]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: Post relevant (the asynctask) code

Comment: it is a simple asynctask that downloads an image from internet in `doInBackground` and then update view with `setImageBitmap` in  `onPostExecute`.